# How to get all users on a PC in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Java, How can I get a list of all local users on a windows machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333812/using-java-how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-local-users-on-a-windows-machine)

Any ideas on how to get all the users on a Windows PC using java? For example, I have a admin account named "Admin" and a non admin account named "User". Any way I can get these values?

Comment: No, you can't get hold of that information without executing native commands (might even be impossible in that case)

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you could try getting it from the Windows "users" folder:

```
List<String> windowsUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
for (File userDirectory : new File("C:/Users").listFiles())
{
    windowsUsers.add(userDirectory);
}
```

Comment: +1 cool this is a possible way but then it is going to vary from win version to win version. One note here: I think you meant `userDirectory.getName()` instead of `userDirectory`.

Comment: Users Directories can have other directories also.So I think this will not work always.