# Java JACOB WMI query for local group membership

Tags: java, wmi, jacob

I am researching how to pull the members of local groups on machines using JACOB.

What I can do: Pull a list of local groups from the machine using separate WMI query.
What I can't do: Pull the members of these groups.

I used the below article to give me the framework of the program: [Using Java, How can I get a list of all local users on a windows machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333812/using-java-how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-local-users-on-a-windows-machine/333848)

Problem: I believe my problem is either in the WMI query I am using or how the program is using the output of the query.

Below is the code I am using.  I included both queries I have used in the code example.  This is in the "instances" Variant.

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent;
import com.jacob.com.ComThread;
import com.jacob.com.EnumVariant;
import com.jacob.com.Variant;

public class WMITest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ComThread.InitMTA();
        try {
            ActiveXComponent wmi = new ActiveXComponent("winmgmts:\\\\.");

            //Variant instances = wmi.invoke("InstancesOf", "Win32_Group Where LocalAccount=True");

            Variant instances = wmi.invoke("InstancesOf", "Win32_GroupUser WHERE GroupComponent=\"Win32_Group.Domain='.',Name='Administrators'\""); 

            Enumeration<Variant> en = new EnumVariant(instances.getDispatch());
            while (en.hasMoreElements())
            {    
                ActiveXComponent bb = new ActiveXComponent(en.nextElement().getDispatch());
                System.out.println(bb.getPropertyAsString("Name"));

            }
        } finally {
            ComThread.Release();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: I fixed the indent for the "}" character.

Comment: I see that the page is rendering strange.  I attempted to fix the indent for the whole code block again.  Thanks for the head's up.

Answer (score -1):

Be careful about query because there must be a space before verbs(where) , please notice my code

```
import com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent;
import com.jacob.com.ComThread;
import com.jacob.com.EnumVariant;
import com.jacob.com.Variant;
import com.jacob.com.Dispatch;

// you have to add Jacob library into your project
// you have to copy  jacob.xx.xx.dll from Jacob Library (both x64 and x86) and paste in c:/...java/jdk/bin (both x64 and x86) 
// you can call any class in WMI by checking  class and prop by using WMI Explorer.


public class GET_COM_PROPERTIES_CLASS {

    // Step 1: Set exported value , you call them from another class.

    public static String COMNAME; //Get Computer Name from Win32_Computersystem-
    public static String SERIAL_NUMBER; //Get Serial Number from Win32_BIOS-
    public static String BIOS_VERSION; //Get Bios Version from Win32_BIOS-
    public static String NOTEBOOK_BRAND; //Get Notebook Brand from Win32_Computersystem-
    public static String DOMAIN; // Get domain from Win32_Computersystem-
    public static String SYSTEM_FAMILY; //Get Laptop model from Win32_Computersystem-
    public static String SYSTEM_TYPE; //Get x64 or x86 from Win32_Computersystem-
    public static String WORKGROUP; //Get Workgroup name from Win32_Computersystem-
    public static String MOTHER_BOARD_PN; //Get ther board partnumber from Win32_MotherboardDevice-
    public static String GRAPHIC_CARD_NAME; //Get graphic car name(Prop: name)Win32_VideoController-
    public static String GRAPHIC_CARD_VER; //Get graphic card version from Win32_VideoController-
    public static String GRAPHIC_SOLUTION; //Get solution of card from Win32_VideoController-
    public static String DISK_SIZE; //Get disk size from Win32_DiskDrive-
    public static String DISK_INTERFACE_TYPE; //Get IDE or other type of interface from Win32_DiskDrive-
    public static String WIN_VERSION; // Get Window version from Win32_OperatingSystem-
    public static String WIN_SERIAL_NUMBER; // Get windows serial number from Win32_OperatingSystem




    public static void main(String[] args) {


        //Step 2: Set Var of ActiveXComponent
        ActiveXComponent wmi_Computersystem, wmi_Win32_BIOS, wmi_Win32_MotherboardDevice, wmi_Win32_VideoController,
        wmi_Win32_DiskDriver, wmi_Win32_OperatingSystem = null;

        //Set SWbemLocator for specify server or your computer and it is used for connect WMI
        wmi_Computersystem = new ActiveXComponent("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
        wmi_Win32_BIOS = new ActiveXComponent("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
        wmi_Win32_MotherboardDevice = new ActiveXComponent("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
        wmi_Win32_VideoController = new ActiveXComponent("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
        wmi_Win32_DiskDriver = new ActiveXComponent("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
        wmi_Win32_OperatingSystem = new ActiveXComponent("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");



        //Step 3: Call method of SWbemLocator to connect server or your computer

        Variant conRet_Computersystem = wmi_Computersystem.invoke("ConnectServer");
        Variant conRet_Win32_BIOS = wmi_Win32_BIOS.invoke("ConnectServer");
        Variant conRet_Win32_MotherboardDevice = wmi_Win32_MotherboardDevice.invoke("ConnectServer");
        Variant conRet_Win32_VideoController = wmi_Win32_VideoController.invoke("ConnectServer");
        Variant conRet_Win32_DiskDriver = wmi_Win32_DiskDriver.invoke("ConnectServer");
        Variant conRet_Win32_OperatingSystem = wmi_Win32_OperatingSystem.invoke("ConnectServer");


        //Step 4: Prepare object for query 
        ActiveXComponent wmiconnect_Computersystem = new ActiveXComponent(conRet_Computersystem.toDispatch());
        ActiveXComponent wmiconnect_Win32_BIOS = new ActiveXComponent(conRet_Win32_BIOS.toDispatch());
        ActiveXComponent wmiconnect_Win32_MotherboardDevice = new ActiveXComponent(conRet_Win32_MotherboardDevice.toDispatch());
        ActiveXComponent wmiconnect_Win32_VideoController = new ActiveXComponent(conRet_Win32_VideoController.toDispatch());
        ActiveXComponent wmiconnect_Win32_DiskDriver = new ActiveXComponent(conRet_Win32_DiskDriver.toDispatch());
        ActiveXComponent wmiconnect_SYSTEM_TYPE = new ActiveXComponent(conRet_Win32_OperatingSystem.toDispatch());



        //Step 5: Set query
        String query_Computersystem = "select Name, Manufacturer, Domain, SystemFamily, SystemType, Workgroup " +
            "from Win32_Computersystem";

        String query_Win32_BIOS = "select SerialNumber, BIOSVersion " +
            "from Win32_BIOS";

        String query_Win32_MotherboardDevice = "select PNPDeviceID " +
            "from Win32_MotherboardDevice";

        String query_Win32_VideoController = "select Name, DriverVersion, VideoModeDescription " +
            "from Win32_VideoController";

        String query_Win32_DiskDrive = "select Size, InterfaceType " +
            "from Win32_DiskDrive";

        String query_Win32_OperatingSystem = "select Caption, SerialNumber " +
            "from Win32_OperatingSystem";

        //Step 6: Set object for enum
        Variant vCollection_Computersystem = wmiconnect_Computersystem.invoke("ExecQuery", new Variant(query_Computersystem));
        Variant vCollection_Win32_BIOS = wmiconnect_Computersystem.invoke("ExecQuery", new Variant(query_Win32_BIOS));
        Variant vCollection_Win32_MotherboardDevice = wmiconnect_Computersystem.invoke("ExecQuery", new Variant(query_Win32_MotherboardDevice));
        Variant vCollection_Win32_VideoController = wmiconnect_Computersystem.invoke("ExecQuery", new Variant(query_Win32_VideoController));
        Variant vCollection_Win32_DiskDrive = wmiconnect_Computersystem.invoke("ExecQuery", new Variant(query_Win32_DiskDrive));
        Variant vCollection_Win32_OperatingSystem = wmiconnect_Computersystem.invoke("ExecQuery", new Variant(query_Win32_OperatingSystem));


        //Step 7: Set Enum and Dispatch object
        EnumVariant enumVariant_Computersystem = new EnumVariant(vCollection_Computersystem.toDispatch());
        EnumVariant enumVariant_Win32_BIOS = new EnumVariant(vCollection_Win32_BIOS.toDispatch());
        EnumVariant enumVariant_Win32_MotherboardDevice = new EnumVariant(vCollection_Win32_MotherboardDevice.toDispatch());
        EnumVariant enumVariant_Win32_VideoController = new EnumVariant(vCollection_Win32_VideoController.toDispatch());
        EnumVariant enumVariant_Win32_DiskDrive = new EnumVariant(vCollection_Win32_DiskDrive.toDispatch());
        EnumVariant enumVariant_Win32_OperatingSystem = new EnumVariant(vCollection_Win32_OperatingSystem.toDispatch());
        Dispatch item_Computersystem, item_Win32_BIOS, item_Win32_MotherboardDevice, item_Win32_VideoController, item_Win32_DiskDrive,
        item_Win32_OperatingSystem = null;

        //Step 8: Set Conmtread for Try  
        ComThread.InitMTA();

        //Step 9: Step Try anf Finally


        try {

            while (enumVariant_Computersystem.hasMoreElements()) {
                //Step 10: Set Item
                item_Computersystem = enumVariant_Computersystem.nextElement().toDispatch();
                item_Win32_BIOS = enumVariant_Win32_BIOS.nextElement().toDispatch();
                item_Win32_MotherboardDevice = enumVariant_Win32_MotherboardDevice.nextElement().toDispatch();
                item_Win32_VideoController = enumVariant_Win32_VideoController.nextElement().toDispatch();
                item_Win32_DiskDrive = enumVariant_Win32_DiskDrive.nextElement().toDispatch();
                item_Win32_OperatingSystem = enumVariant_Win32_OperatingSystem.nextElement().toDispatch();


                // call prop of Win32_ComputerSystem
                COMNAME = Dispatch.call(item_Computersystem, "Name").toString();
                NOTEBOOK_BRAND = Dispatch.call(item_Computersystem, "Manufacturer").toString();
                DOMAIN = Dispatch.call(item_Computersystem, "Domain").toString();
                SYSTEM_FAMILY = Dispatch.call(item_Computersystem, "SystemFamily").toString();
                SYSTEM_TYPE = Dispatch.call(item_Computersystem, "SystemType").toString();
                WORKGROUP = Dispatch.call(item_Computersystem, "Workgroup").toString();

                // call prop of Win32_BIOS
                SERIAL_NUMBER = Dispatch.call(item_Win32_BIOS, "SerialNumber").toString();
                BIOS_VERSION = Dispatch.call(item_Win32_BIOS, "BIOSVersion").toString();

                //call prop of Win32_MotherboardDevice
                MOTHER_BOARD_PN = Dispatch.call(item_Win32_MotherboardDevice, "PNPDeviceID").toString();

                //call prop of Win32_VideoController
                GRAPHIC_CARD_NAME = Dispatch.call(item_Win32_VideoController, "Name").toString();
                GRAPHIC_CARD_VER = Dispatch.call(item_Win32_VideoController, "DriverVersion").toString();
                GRAPHIC_SOLUTION = Dispatch.call(item_Win32_VideoController, "VideoModeDescription").toString();

                //call prop of Win32_DiskDrive
                DISK_SIZE = Dispatch.call(item_Win32_DiskDrive, "Size").toString();
                DISK_INTERFACE_TYPE = Dispatch.call(item_Win32_DiskDrive, "InterfaceType").toString();

                //call prop of Win32_OperatingSystem
                WIN_VERSION = Dispatch.call(item_Win32_OperatingSystem, "Caption").toString();
                WIN_SERIAL_NUMBER = Dispatch.call(item_Win32_OperatingSystem, "SerialNumber").toString();




                //output for Win32_Computersystem
                System.out.println("Computer Name : " + COMNAME + "\n");
                System.out.println("Notebook Brand : " + NOTEBOOK_BRAND + "\n");
                System.out.println("Domain Name : " + DOMAIN + "\n");
                System.out.println("System Family : " + SYSTEM_FAMILY + "\n");
                System.out.println("System Type : " + SYSTEM_TYPE + "\n");
                System.out.println("Workgroup Name : " + WORKGROUP + "\n");

                //output for Win32_BIOS
                System.out.println("Serial Number : " + SERIAL_NUMBER + "\n");
                System.out.println("Bios Version : " + BIOS_VERSION + "\n");

                //output for Win32_MotherboardDevice 
                System.out.println("MotherBoard Part Number : " + MOTHER_BOARD_PN + "\n");

                //output for Win32_VideoController
                System.out.println("Graphic Card Name : " + GRAPHIC_CARD_NAME + "\n");
                System.out.println("Graphic Card Version : " + GRAPHIC_CARD_VER + "\n");
                System.out.println("Graphic Version : " + GRAPHIC_SOLUTION + "\n");

                //output for  Win32_DiskDrive
                System.out.println("Disk Size : " + DISK_SIZE + "\n");
                System.out.println("Disk Interface Type : " + DISK_INTERFACE_TYPE + "\n");

                //output for Win32_OperatingSystem
                System.out.println("Windows Version : " + WIN_VERSION + "\n");
                System.out.println("Windows Serial Number : " + WIN_SERIAL_NUMBER + "\n");

                break;

            }
        } finally {
            ComThread.Release();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: He *does* have a space before `WHERE`. So what does your answer actually consist of?

Comment: And what terrible code. All the variables from `wmi_Computersystem` to `wmi_Win32_OperatingSystem`, and `conRet_Computersystem ` to `conRet_Win32_OperatingSystem`, and `wmiconnect_Computersystem` to `wmiconnect_SYSTEM_TYPE`, respectively, are initialized the same way. You only need one of each of these.